# I am looking for an alert configuration for locked tables in waiting state in mysql on grafana and with prometheus data source

Tags: prometheus

I have a panel with these requests, how to configure an alert that is triggered every time there are 10 table locks waited:

```
rate(mysql_global_status_table_locks_immediate{instance="$host"}[$interval]) or irate(mysql_global_status_table_locks_immediate{instance="$host"}[5m])

rate(mysql_global_status_table_locks_waited{instance="$host"}[$interval]) or irate(mysql_global_status_table_locks_waited{instance="$host"}[5m])

mysql_global_status_table_locks_waited{instance="$host"}
```

I made a configuration based on this query: `mysql_global_status_table_locks_waited{instance="$host"}`
As soon as this superior reaches 10, send me an alert. Is this a good configuration.